# Eclipse: one PhoneGap project for iPhone and Android?

Tags: iphone, android, eclipse, cordova

I'm trying out PhoneGap, so I followed the instructions to create an Android Project in Eclipse.

But now I'm wondering how I can use this same code for building an iPhone app.

Is there something like a hybrid project in Eclipse!?

***UPDATE:***
I realize now that it's not possible to use PhoneGap on Windows to develop iPhone apps?  That's too bad... is there any way to use PhoneGap on Windows to compile for iOS ??

Comment: On windows platform, it is impossible, you can use VMWare for this purpose.

Comment: Phonegap Build is the way to go. You only need to borrow a Mac for a few hours when you're finally ready to publish to the App Store. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11998668/phonegap-w-visualstudio-for-iphone-itouch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to develop iPhone app on Windows using PhoneGap or Titanium.
Because they need iPhone SDK and Android SDK on back-end, which is not possible on windows environment. However you can make both apps on iOS simulations.

Answer (score 1):

In theory [PhoneGap build](https://build.phonegap.com/) should allow iPhone development on Windows.

However Nitobi was bought out by Adobe (PhoneGap:Build service may have changed), and you may still need iOS to upload your app (might be able to get around with a jailbroken iOS?!).

A dodgy solution could be to install OSX in a vbox virtual machine :)